# Slick DBIO.sequence throws No implicits found for parameter cbf: compat.Factory

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have the following model:

```
case class Bar(id: Int, code: Option[String])

class BarTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Bar](tag, "bar") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def code = column[Option[String]]("code")

    def * = (id, code).mapTo[Bar]
}

object BarTable extends TableQuery(new BarTable(_)) {
    def create(bar: Bar): DBIO[Bar] = {
        this returning this.map(_.id) into ((t, id) => t.copy(id = id)) += bar
    }
}
```

I try to insert multiple `Bar` in one transaction:

```
def foo(codes: Seq[String]): Seq[Bar] = exec {
    for {
        bars <- DBIO.sequence(codes.map{code=>
            BarTable.create(Bar(0, Some(code)))
        })
    } yield bars
}

private final def exec[T](program: DBIO[T]): T = Await.result(connection.run(program.transactionally), Duration.Inf)
```

But the code above yields error in my IDE:

**No implicits found for parameter cbf: compat.Factory[Bar, Seq[Bar]]**

What do I miss?

Do note that if I only insert one (that is, no `map`/`DBIO.sequence`), the code compiles.